# Load Images in Runtime

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I'm using opencv and face recognition model to detect and Identify the face in webcam.

I saw that all Images in folder are encoded once then search faces .. but if I add the image in runtime it'll not pick up that image

can anyone help , how to load images in runtime if Images are not found in particular folder

Thanks,
Chiranjit

Comment: I would be good if you share your current code

Comment: It's not clear whether you're reading images from disk or whether you're using a live video stream from your webcam.

Comment: Hi, I have stored images in particular folder in disk .. and I'm opening webcam using cv2..and compare faces .. If it matches it will say my Name...

All the images on that disk encoded once then compare face, If I add images in runtime It will not pick that latest image...